# Oracle SQL: Combine list of char with values

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle SQL, I want to create a view.

In Column 1, it should have a distinct list of chars.

```
select distinct *name* from view1
--> name1
    name2
    name3
    name4...
```

Now in the second column, there should be numbers, which depend on this number:

```
select max(number) number_max from view2
--> 17
```

Now I want the second column to be ascending, depending on that number. The list of numbers for each name. The table should look like:

```
name1 18  ->(number_max+1)
name1 19  ->(number_max+2)
name1 20
name2 18
name2 19
name2 20
name3 18
....
```

How do I do this? Thank you so much!

Comment: Your first query does a distinct select, but the expected output has duplicate names.  Please explain what is going on here.

Comment: The view1, where I am getting the names from, is different to the view im building. So I just need the distinct names to perform a join with the number_max´s. If it would not be distinct, the first column would be completely wrong. Like there woudl be 10x name1, but I only need 3. Does that make sense?

Comment: view2 also has values "name1", "name2"... ?

Comment: And do you need an actual output _table_, or would a select/view be acceptable?

Comment: view2 does have the values "name1" etc., yes

Comment: A view would not only be acceptable, but needed :D

Answer (score 2):

This is how I understood it:

Sample data (your views, `view1` and `view2`, simplified):

```
SQL> with
  2  view1 (name) as
  3    (select 'name1' from dual union all
  4     select 'name1' from dual union all
  5     select 'name1' from dual union all
  6     select 'name2' from dual union all
  7     select 'name3' from dual union all
  8     select 'name3' from dual
  9    ),
 10  view2 (c_number) as
 11    (select 15 from dual union all
 12     select 17 from dual
 13    )
 14  --
```

Query begins here; subquery that is cross-joined to `view1` just fetches the maximum number column value which is then added to result of the `row_number` analytic function that partitions data per each `name`:

```
 15  select
 16    a.name as col1,
 17    row_number() over (partition by a.name order by null) + b.number_max as col2
 18  from view1 a cross join (select max(c_number) number_max from view2) b
 19  order by 1, 2;

COL1        COL2
----- ----------
name1         18
name1         19
name1         20
name2         18
name3         18
name3         19

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks so much Littlefoot! This works so far, but I noticed that I didnt describe it well and completely.

In your solution, the combination of col1 and col2 depends on a.name... where col2 is the rownumber of the names. 

Now, what I need is, that "name1" appears 6 times (number I decided) and col2 goes from number_max to number_max+6...

So I need name1 17, name1 18.... name1 23, name2 17...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY name` to find the `DISTINCT` names and find the maximum maximum by nesting an `MAX` aggregation function inside a `MAX` analytic function and then `CROSS JOIN` to a row-generator.

For example, if you wanted 3 rows for each `name`:

```sql
SELECT m.name,
       m.number_max + l.value AS value
FROM   ( SELECT name,
                MAX(MAX("NUMBER")) OVER () AS number_max
         FROM   table_name
         GROUP BY name
       ) m
       CROSS JOIN (
         SELECT LEVEL AS value FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3
       ) l;
```

Which, if you have the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (name, "NUMBER") AS
SELECT 'name1', 17 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'name1',  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'name1',  7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'name2', 15 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'name2', 15 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'name3',  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'name3',  7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'name4',  2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'name4',  1 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | NAME | VALUE |
> | --- | --- |
> | name1 | 18 |
> | name2 | 18 |
> | name3 | 18 |
> | name4 | 18 |
> | name1 | 19 |
> | name2 | 19 |
> | name3 | 19 |
> | name4 | 19 |
> | name1 | 20 |
> | name2 | 20 |
> | name3 | 20 |
> | name4 | 20 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e78f7bf23f9faea9136ae99ee137764b)*